# Problema con formulario fácil

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una página con un formulario en el que hay que rellenar el campo usuario y seleccionar un ingrediente con select. Tengo que comprobar que el usuario que se introduce está en la base de datos. Para ello tengo este código que funciona:

```
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
if( !( $usuario == "" ) ){
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
    $con=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
        if($con == 0){
            echo"Usuario inexistente. Introduzca un usuario registrado";
        }else{
            $con==1;
        }
    }
```

Si añado este código:

```
if($ingrediente==""){
   echo "Seleccione una ingrediente";
}
```

Cuando introduzco un usuario que si está registrado pero no selecciono ningún ingrediente, me aparece únicamente el echo de que seleccione un ingrediente.

Debajo debo colocar el código que trata que al introducir un usuario que está en la base de datos y que además se selecciona un ingrediente, me aparezcan los apellidos de la persona que he introducido. Este es el código que funciona:

```
if (isset($_POST['ingrediente']) && ($con == 1)){

        $resultadoConsulta="SELECT apellidos FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
        $sql=mysqli_query($con, $resultadoConsulta);

                $fila=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
                while ($fila != null){
                    $fila['apellidos'];
                    echo "Apellidos: " .$fila['apellidos'];
                    $fila= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
                }       
    }
```

El problema aparece al poner este código debajo del otro, cuando introduzco un usuario pero no selecciono ningún ingrediente, en vez de salirme el echo Seleccione un ingrediente únicamente, me aparece Seleccione un ingrediente y debajo el echo de los apellidos sin haber seleccionado el ingrediente. No se por qué pasa eso, debe ser muy tonto pero no encuentro la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los parámetros que se pasan por un formulario van a estar definidos (su `isset` será verdadero) incluso si su valor es la cadena vacía. Es por ello que no solo deberías comprobar el `isset` sino también [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) para asegurarse de que no están vacíos (que parece el caso de la pregunta). Como `empty` comprueba si l variable está definida solo tendrías que usar ese.

Cambia el `if` a esto:

```
if (!empty($_POST['ingrediente']) && ($con == 1)){
  ...
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Alvaro ya funciona!